# How do code (SQL) a combo box to display data from a field in a table, minus data which is also in another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I'm using SQL to code a combobox which will display names from one table (students), minus any students in my other table (Bookings) who have made a booking on a specific day.

In my "students" table I have one field, "Name". In my "Bookings" table I have two fields, "Name" and "Day".

Here is the code I am using to tell what is going in my combobox;

```
Combobox.RowSource = "SELECT Name FROM Students" & _
                     "LEFT OUTER JOIN Bookings " & _
                     "ON Students.Name = Bookings.Name" & _
                     "WHERE Bookings.Day = 'Monday';"
```

To my knowledge this should display all of the names in Students.Name minus any names in Bookings which are on the day Monday. But it's just opening an error message "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Udate:

I found out how to make it work. Instead of a "Left Outer Join" you have to use a "Not In" clause.
Here' s the code I used.

```
combobox.RowSource = "SELECT Name FROM Students " & _
                     "WHERE Name " & _
                     "NOT IN (SELECT Bookings.Name FROM Bookings WHERE Bookings.Day = ""Monday"") "
```

Comment: Line 1 and line 3 need a trailing space before the closing quote.  While that cures the error msg, the sql will show only those students that have booked on Monday.  you need more work on that.

Comment: LOJ needs to be (Select * from Bookings where Day = "Monday") as BK,  the ON needs to refer to BK.Name,     and then the final Where needs to be WHERE BK.Name Is Null  in order to exclude those Monday students